# Delete document with OR pattern - MongoDb and mongo-migrate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, migration, database-migration

I use mongo-migrate to configure my database content, create collections and documents and so on.

Now, I'm trying to delete in the `down` method all the created document, I'm kinda new at mongodb, mongoose, mongo-migrate. I followed the instructions there: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/ (OR part)

**Source code:**

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

exports.up = function(db, next){

    var documentName = 'category';
    var collection = mongodb.Collection(db, documentName);
    collection.insert({
        code: 'a',
        name: 'languageStatus'
    }, function(error, data){
        console.log(error ? error : documentName + ': ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    collection.insert({
        code: 'b',
        name: 'accessName'
    }, function(error, data){
        console.log(error ? error : documentName + ': ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    collection.insert({
        code: 'c',
        name: 'roleName'
    }, function(error, data){
        console.log(error ? error : documentName + ': ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    collection.insert({
        code: 'd',
        name: 'translationStatus'
    }, function(error, data){
        console.log(error ? error : documentName + ': ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    next();
};

exports.down = function(db, next){
    var documentName = 'category';
    var document = mongodb.Collection(db, documentName);

    var query = {
        $or: [
            {name: 'languageStatus'},
            {name: 'accessName'},
            {name: 'roleName'},
            {name: 'translationStatus'}
        ]
    };
    document.findAndModify(query, [], {}, { remove: true }, function(error, data){
        console.log(error ? error : 'Deleted: ' + documentName + ': ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    next();
};
```

In console I get:

**Up**:

```
category: [{"code":"a","name":"languageStatus","_id":"52f535d71a60eedc7c1685d4"}]
category: [{"code":"b","name":"accessName","_id":"52f535d71a60eedc7c1685d5"}]
category: [{"code":"c","name":"roleName","_id":"52f535d71a60eedc7c1685d6"}]
category: [{"code":"d","name":"translationStatus","_id":"52f535d71a60eedc7c1685d7"}]
```

**Down**:

```
Deleted: category: {"code":"a","name":"languageStatus","_id":"52f535d71a60eedc7c1685d4"}
```

What's wrong with my `down` query?

PS: I just thought about the findAndModify... Hum, I guess it returns only the first result, makes sense. But how can I do to remove these documents ? I just found the `remove` method but there is no callback.

**Edit**:
It was because of the `findAndModify`, of course. So I changed the source code but I get another issue that I don't understand:

```
exports.down = function(db, next){
    var documentName = 'category';
    var document = mongodb.Collection(db, documentName);

    var query = {
        $or: [
            {name: 'languageStatus'},
            {name: 'accessName'},
            {name: 'roleName'},
            {name: 'translationStatus'}
        ]
    };
    document.find(query, function(error, data){
        data.each(function(error, data){
            console.log(data)
            document.remove(data, function(error, number){
                console.log(error ? error : documentName + ': (' + number + ') ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            })
        });
    });

    next();
};
```

*Console*:

```
down : migrations/0010-init_category_table.js
{ code: 'a',
  name: 'languageStatus',
  _id: 52f53e2d3f852ed04d785e4c }
{ code: 'b', name: 'accessName', _id: 52f53e2d3f852ed04d785e4d }
{ code: 'c', name: 'roleName', _id: 52f53e2d3f852ed04d785e4e }
{ code: 'd',
  name: 'translationStatus',
  _id: 52f53e2d3f852ed04d785e4f }
null
category: (1) {"code":"b","name":"accessName","_id":"52f53e2d3f852ed04d785e4d"}
  migration : complete
```

So, on the first console log, there are 4 iterations, no problem. But in the callback of the remove() method, I get only one?! I don't understand, I should get 4 messages here too.
And I don't understand the null, it's from the first console.log.

What's strange is that I get one message about the remove() callback, but all the documents are correctly deleted in the DB.

Comment: Basically, the callback must be the second argument to the `remove` method. But I get only the number of row deleted.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you call [**remove**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/).

The link is to the MongoDB general documentation. A bit better than elsewhere.

You are using `data` as the argument being passed in but what you actually want is `query`. So the argument isn't what documents to remove, it's the query to find them.

Comment: I tried to do following the doc, but I get this:
`Error: Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback`. Plus I wanted to have a message to detail each deleted data.

Comment: I found this link and I see three arguments at the `Collection.remove` method. Not just two like in the previous link. i don't really understand! http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html

Comment: I just did a `console.log(collection.remove.toString())` to see what's the function and there is 3 args, not only two! `function remove(selector, options, callback)`